# How to move SNOWPIPE from one schema to another?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how can i move snowpipe from one schema to another ? Does it replace if i use the following command?

`Create or replace pipe <target_schema>.<mypipe_name>  as`

I couldn't find an alter statement to rename pipe or change schema.

Answer (score 1):

You do a clone, there are some considerations wrt to how you have defined the pipe source, fully qualified name versus just the pipe name.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-clone.html#cloning-and-pipes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Cloning or replacing pipe seems to lose its history of files that were copied. Is there a way to move clone object from one schema to another?